# Laws regarding amateur chemistry sets for lawful and safe exploration of science

Tags: civil-law, regulations, reference-request

Last week a squad of 20 members of the weapons of mass destruction division of the FBI shut down my block and raided my apartment. They didn't find what they'd expected to find (basically they found a nerd with a chemistry set) but it reminded me there has got to be some degree of civil regulatory oversight of possession and use of chemicals and safety standards and the like. I live in California and also spend a lot of time in texas. I'm hoping someone may be able to provide a reference to either the codified location of the law, or perhaps even be familiar with what (if any) restrictions there would be for a person playing around with chemicals in their dwelling.

Comment: Self-Answer: In Texas, purchase of most chemistry glassware without a permit is a felony (class-state jail). See Health and Safety Code Sec 481.002(53) for list of controlled glassware. Sec 481.081 establishes the permit requirement. Sec 481.138 establishes its criminal nature.

Comment: Update: As of Summer 2019-ish the laws in Texas regarding permits for glassware have been repealed. https://www.dps.texas.gov/RSD/Precursor/News/index.htm